# How would you deal with emotions of meta / moderator when they feel criticized?

Tags: discussion

This question was close as too broad:
[Free secure wipe software for Windows that processes free space](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/free-secure-wipe-software-for-windows-that-processes-free-space?noredirect=1#comment2078_1082)

Oxinabox says:

**This question seems, narrow enough.** @Sam: I suspect you may be getting unintentional (subconscious) bias against you because of your behaviour, both in comments, in other questions and in meta.

**My answer is:**
 I've studied a bit of psychology and criticizing people is the best way to make enemies. The more they are childish the more it happens.. Psychology also explains that almost every one has strong "personality trait" (obsessive, narcisistic, maniacal, ipomaniacal). But meta and moderator should try to control themself.. otherwise should avoid that kind of work.. IMHO. I don't want anyone to take these sentence as an offence. They are not. They are just objective studies that invites people to think about

**How would you deal with emotions of meta / moderator when they feel criticized?**

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange site but more a general discussion about emotions?

Comment: @Sam, I will repeat my other comment :
 You seem to misunderstand what Meta is, it is not a group of people (it is a subsite of this one, that anyone can go on). Also we don't have moderators, as we are in early beta. We allow anyone to close vote a question. We are occationally frequented by Stack Exchange Staff. But in my experience they are all excellent and absolutely beyond repute.

Comment: I think I will delete these question, but @Oxinabox: you wrote this comment.. "This question seems, narrow enough. I suspect you may be getting unintentional (subconscious) bias against you because of your behaviour, both in comments, in other questions and in meta." --> you know there is an issue here.. help me to discuss the need for better guidelines for this section.. What happened to me shouldn't repeat.. Questions like that are narrow enough. What can we do to state this?

Comment: @Sam: How many questions here on meta are you intending to post because of your question being closed on the main site?

Comment: I don't think there is a issue Sam. 
Not an issue with the Site.
Perhaps an issue with someone not understanding the site.

Comment: @juergend: It's not for the closed question. It's because too many questions are being closed for the "wrong" reasons. So I'd like to help this community to review the guidelines. **One error was documented (the question got reopened). Now we should understand how to avoid that this errors happens again. All of those errors are due to excess of addiction to rules in a really hurried behaviour.**

Comment: @Oxinabox: come on guy, you sayid there was an error in your comment. The question was reopened. There are evidence of a mistake happened. The question wasn't too broad at all. How can we improve the guidelines for this section for closing question as too broad?

Comment: It was no Error. There is no Error, that needs to be prevented occuring again. the Community self moderates to equilibrium. The Community works to gether and reaches consensu on its standards, and part of that consensus it done by closing and reopening. Closes that are revoked will naturally decrease as the community gets better consesus, but we don't need more words to communicate, we speak through out actions and our observations of others actions

Comment: @Sam: Almost all your meta posts are downvoted. Maybe **you** should adapt to the community and not the other way around.

Comment: Are you for real, or is this a breaching experiment?

Answer (score 7):

The question was reopened.

Meta has no feelings. It has no remorse. It absolutely will not stop until you change its water... Wait, that's goldfish.

Meta is a place - it's meant for meta discussions. Upvotes and downvotes here have no consequence other than agreement or disagreement. Unless you manage to annoy enough *individuals* meta is unlikely to hold a grudge, or (much like a goldfish) even remember your posts specifically.

As for moderators, as I've always said, they're janitors. They have the difficult task of balancing user happiness, with quality, and often the needs and wants of a new user may be different from someone who's been a while.

I see a question. I *don't* see who posted it (unless I suspect obvious sockpuppeting). I decide on its own merits whether I can answer it, or whether its within the scope of the site, or whether its been asked before or not.

No one's out to get you. You're just posting things in a manner that people disagree with. In some cases, they seem to reflect to me, a misunderstanding of how things work.

A week, a month, a year from now, or even tomorrow, I'm not going to remember what I upvoted, downvoted, or even answered. The only real emotions you need to deal with are your own. You're getting kind of worked up over this, posting lots of meta questions. It might help a lot to step back, and self evaluate a little.

Answer (score 5):

The site has intrinsic properties that minimise the effects of personal bias.

- Targeted downvoting and upvoting against an individual are detected and reverted.
- Close votes need 5 people to approve them
- A down vote costs the user 1 rep to give a -2 rep the person whose question they dislike.

Worst that can happen, by someone acting in away the community disapproves of, in terms of bias, is that they will attract more attention from people who think:

"This guy is not very good in this question, lets check his other questions."

So they suffer additional scrutiny.
It is the extra scrutiny that I was referring to in my comment.

Comment: I upvoted you since your answer is right. But as you see mistakes happens and SE is becoming really rule addicted, emotionally biased and so on. Sometime I open the same identical question and it became closed as too broad one time and the other time it became very constructive. 

I've documented that 5 guys are easily to be hurried and make a mistake, and this is happening a lot of times.. this is not good for this community. The problem are not the rules, but their excessive (wrong) usage without flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Flyk. This is one of the great things about SE.

Comment: @Sam: You seem to be both complaining about too much application of rules, and yet you want to solve it by creating more rules.

Comment: @Sam: The difference in why it is different sometimes when you repost is becuase different people are online.

instead of Reposting your questions (which is against the rules), let them sit for a 24 hours. The community will naturally balance, as the same different people will see your closed question and will reopen it.

Comment: @Sam I agree that close-vote are often far more easily given than the first close-vote, but I don't think this meta is the place to discuss that. But I also agree with Oxinabox, if a question is closed for the wrong reasons, it is often reopened later!

Comment: @Sam I see there is also another question of yours discussing this issue. Not really sure why we are also discussing this here? This confuses me.